# How can i solve the error while deploying the webpart into the sitecollection?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

While deploying the webpart into the site collection using central administration wizard ,I am receiving the error like this.

Error: Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache: System.Web.DataVisualization.dll.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 0faee23c-f6f0-4frr-8463-2ef5fdc8bfc4

can anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That assembly is part of the MS Chart Controls. They may not be installed on your server. Try installing them first and then re-deploy your webpart. The controls can be downloaded here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14422

You may also need to do an IISRESET to release open handles to the assembly.

Comment: Also, do not include such system DLLs in your custom WSP package.